# Run bundled executable file Ubuntu server

Tags: ubuntu, mono, monodevelop

I am trying to run a gtk "Hello World" application on Ubuntu.
I have created bundle of the .exe by using following command.(Ref: [How to create bundle for Mono develop](http://www.mono-project.com/Mono%3aRuntime#Bundles))

> mkbundle --static hello.exe -o hello

Now, I am trying to run this bundled application on fresh ubuntu server by using following command:

> anand@anand-Fresh-Ubuntu:~Desktop$ ./ hello

It is throwing following error:

> Unhandled Exception: System.TypeInitializationException: An exception
>   was thrown by the type initializer for Gtk.Application --->
>   System.EntryPointNotFoundException: glibsharp_g_thread_supported   at
>   (wrapper managed-to-native) GLib.Thread:glibsharp_g_thread_supported
>   ()   at GLib.Thread.get_Supported () [0x00000] in :0
>   at Gtk.Application..cctor () [0x00000] in :0    ---
>   End of inner exception stack trace ---   at Test.MainClass.Main
>   (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in :0  [ERROR]
>   FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.TypeInitializationException: An
>   exception was thrown by the type initializer for Gtk.Application --->
>   System.EntryPointNotFoundException: glibsharp_g_thread_supported   at
>   (wrapper managed-to-native) GLib.Thread:glibsharp_g_thread_supported
>   ()   at GLib.Thread.get_Supported () [0x00000] in :0
>   at Gtk.Application..cctor () [0x00000] in :0    ---
>   End of inner exception stack trace ---   at Test.MainClass.Main
>   (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in :0

mono-complete is already installed on this machine.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes using mono framework.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is although mkbundle includes managed assemblies, it does not include the native libraries that they P/Invoke into, in this case libglibsharpglue.

Comment: Then what should be the best way to run mono developed bundled?